# wpf application exits on first async call

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a wpf application that for works perfectly for most users, however, for about 10% of the users the application quits immediately after startup when I call the first async function, here's a snippet of the startup code

from app.xaml.cs:

```
    private static app application;
    private view app_view;
    public TaskbarIcon sys_tray_icon;

    private async Task init_remote_conf(){
        // XXX: debug start->exit bug
        log.write_debug("before simple_task");
        await util.sleep_async(500);
        log.write_debug("before get_server_conf_async");
        // ........ other async init calls
    }

    private async void startup_cb(){
        util.cleanup_tray_icons();
        sys_tray_icon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("tray_icon");
        sys_tray_icon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        app_view = new view(application);
        sys_tray_icon.DataContext = app_view;
        conf.get_cmd_args();
        sys_tray_icon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        log.perr("start", true);
        await init_remote_conf();
        log.write_debug("after init_remote_conf");
        // ......... other startup code
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e){
        sys_tray_icon.CloseBalloon();
        sys_tray_icon.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(e);
    }

    private void exit_cb(string reason){
        log.perr("exit", "reason: "+reason, null, null, true, true);
    }

    private static bool unhandled_exception_sent = false;
    private static void crash_cb(Exception e){
        if (unhandled_exception_sent)
            return;
        log.perr("unhandled_exception", e.Message, e.StackTrace, null,
            true, true);
        unhandled_exception_sent = true;
        // Exit event isn't called if we're in error state
        application.exit_cb("unhandled_exception");
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        if (!SingleInstance<app>.InitializeAsFirstInstance(unique))
            return;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
            (s, e) => crash_cb((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
        log.init();
        application = new app();
        application.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, e) => {
            crash_cb(e.Exception); };
        application.Exit += (s, e) =>
            application.exit_cb(e.ApplicationExitCode.ToString());
        application.SessionEnding += (s, e) => {
            log.perr("session_ending", e.ReasonSessionEnding.ToString(),
                null, null, true, true);
        };
        application.Startup += (s, e) => application.startup_cb();
        application.Run();
        // Allow single instance code to perform cleanup operations
        SingleInstance<app>.Cleanup();
    }
```

from util.cs:

```
public static async Task<bool> sleep_async(int ms){
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms); });
        return true;
    }
```

Now, for most users the debug prints generate:

> before simple_task
>   before get_server_conf_async
>   after init_remote_conf

But for the few unlucky ones, they only get

> before simple_task

and immediately the application exit_cb is called.

The sleep_async was added only to debug the behavior (before any other more complicated async tasks).

I can't figure out what can cause the application to call shutdown so soon after start.

**Edit** (More info):

- This issue happens on all supported os versions (7,8,8.1,10 32/64bit).
- I've ruled out AV/Firewall interference (some users only have the basic windows security essentials or defender which doesn't actually do anything).
- application is compiled on .NET 3.5 AnyCPU but supports working with newer .NET versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: .NET 3.5 does not even support TPL, so I wonder how your project is able to achieve so. Meanwhile, the current information you had is almost useless. Try to get a crash dump and that can lead you quickly to the cause.

Comment: @Lex Li: I'm using the "Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5" and "AsyncBridge - Async Support for .NET 3.5" packages embedded in the assembly. In any case I'll add code to generate a memory dump on the exit event, hopefully that helps

Comment: Does your log actually display "exit"? If not your log isn't explicitly flush when exiting the application which mean it could be an exception throw while initializing the main WPF windows.
In such case the application exit without VisualStudio (if you do debug) even telling you about any exception, you have to rely on try/catch or UnhandledException event to catch the exception.

Comment: @0xCDCDCDCD: Yes, I see the exit in the log (it's actually a post to the server with the full run log).

Comment: Doesn't the AsyncBridge have `TaskEx.Run` and `TaskEx.Delay` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why this happens and want to share for future reference.

When all wpf applications init examples set the Application MainWindow shortly before or after the call to Application.Run, there's a very good reason for that.

I was setting my main window after the async calls at the end of my startup_cb code. On some machines under some circumstances this was causing wpf to think the application is in shutdown criteria and call Shutdown.

Moving main window set to the beginning of the start_cb resolved the issue.